# How do I generate a css file using webpack 4 and mini-css-extract-plugin?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, mini-css-extract-plugin

I was able to get min-css-extract-plugin top generate css files just fine, but I can't seem to get it working with SASS. It runs great when I'm using the webpack dev server, but it keeps inserting my scss into my javascript file instead of creating a separate CSS file.

I have index.html, index.js and main.scss stored under /src

webpack.config.js:

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin")


module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          // fallback to style-loader in development
          process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? 'style-loader' : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          "css-loader",
          "sass-loader"
      ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css",
      chunkFilename: "[id].css"
    })
  ]
}
```

Comment: What is in your index.js file?

Comment: Does the build create a CSS file in your output folder? If so, you might just need to use HtmlWebpackPlugin to load it in index.html. The css is working fine on the dev server because style-loader is injecting it as <style> tags at the top of the page.

Answer (score 5):

To have `mini-css-extract-plugin` actually extract your CSS into a separate file, you need to import your CSS (or other extension) into an `entry` file (`index.js` in your case). Additionally, using `process.env.NODE_ENV`'s value to determine development or production settings inside your Webpack configuration does not actually work.

From Webpack's [production configuration guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/#specify-the-mode):

> *Contrary to expectations, `process.env.NODE_ENV` is not set to `"production"` **within** the build script `webpack.config.js`, see [#2537](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2537). Thus, conditionals like `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '[name].[hash].bundle.js' : '[name].bundle.js'` within webpack configurations do not work as expected.*

You'll need to write your CSS rule without the `style-loader` for `mini-css-extract-plugin`'s loader to take effect:

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  use: [
    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
    "css-loader",
    "sass-loader"
  ]
}
```

Then, since you remove `style-loader` from the rule, you need to create separate Webpack configurations for production and development so you can use it in development.